# Video.js poster frame too big on iPod Touch 5G

Tags: video.js, ipod-touch

I embedded a video on my 'responsive' web page built with RapidWeaver, and my video plays OK on both desktop Safari and Firefox.

But on my iPod Touch 4G the poster image does not shrink enough for the play arrow to be visible, I just see the lefthand half of the poster image. After repeated tapping, the video plays, but the initial impression does not look good and inconvenient to use.

I used to have this problem with older versions of JWPlayer, where the poster size was specified in pixels HxW, but the latest version of that player uses a script that just says that the poster image width is 100%, and now the poster image fits nicely across the width of the iPod Touch screen.

Answer (score 0):

I was building a Drupal site, where I had a video on the front page with the same problem. This is how I fixed it:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .video-js {
    zoom: .7;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 460px) {
  .video-js {
    zoom: .73 !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

change `.7` and `.73` to whatever numbers make your video fit best with trial and error.